# PHP5 UTF-8 encoding error - PHP4 works fine

Tags: php, encoding, utf-8

i'm having some troubles with UTF-8 encoding on a website. Calling my script using PHP5 all the umlauts (ä, ü, ö,...) look like this: Ã¶kflÃ¶dskÃ¶l

Calling the script using PHP4 shows everything as expected...

both php.ini look the same an so my question would be:

is there an other file where i can change the output encoding?

Thanks

Comment: We can't tell without the code you're using.

Comment: Encoding is confusing - could be a PHP thing, an Apache thing or a MySql thing (assuming you're on *AMP )

Comment: echo '<h1>'.nl2br(htmlentities($elem->headline)).'</h1>';

while $elem->headline is a String comming out of a Database.

Comment: Are you testing with a web browser? What encoding is sent in the headers?

Comment: oh thanks, encoding is iso-8859-1, don't know why but i'm going to change this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to tell htmlentities to use UTF-8

```
htmlentities($foo, null, 'UTF-8');
```

I hope that helps :)

Answer (score 0):

New Status: if i remove `htmlentities()` it all looks great...